# EXCEPTION: Unexpected token n in JSON at position 10

Tags: json, angular

I need a help for my bug .
I work with angular2 and i get error.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {Http} from '@angular/http';

import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()

export class PeopleService {

  constructor(private _http: Http) { }
  fetchPeople(){
    return this._http.get('/assets/people.json')
                .map(res => res.json());
 }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hivp6.png)};

Comment: can you post your json?and did you make sure it's valid?

Comment: you can use http://jsonlint.com/ to test your JSON

Comment: And your question is...

Answer (score 1):

Very simple - Check the JSON returned, 10th character. Something is wrong there. This error means that the JSON cannot be parsed because of invalid structure. Make sure the JSON is well formatted:

`Unexpected token n` so - the JSON has an `n` character in position 10 that breaks its format. Check that you closed all data with `{}` and `[]`.

Comment: Thanks  to Koby Douek

Answer (score 0):

JSON file is not valid. strings should use double quote.

e.g. 
[{
    "name": "Smael Check",
    "status": "Web developper"
}]